# R replace characters in a column based on a word in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `dataset` that has multiple columns. In the `Date_Received` column there are certain rows that have the word `Abandonment` in them. I would like to search the rows in this column that have this word, and then replace the characters `AP` with `AB` in the corresponding rows of the `AP` column.

How can I do this?

Sample data `df`:

```
structure(list(id = 1:6, Date_Received = c("Addition 1/2/2018", 
"Swimming Pool 1/8/2018", "Swimming Pool 1/8/2018", "Abandonment 1/9/2018", 
"Swimming Pool 1/12/2017", "Abandonment 2/5/2018"), Date_Approved = c("1/2/2018", 
"1/8/2018", "1/8/2018", "1/9/2018", "1/12/2017", "2/5/2018"), 
    AP= c("AP-18-001", "AP-18-002", "AP-18-003", "AP-18-004", 
    "AP-18-005", "AP-18-006"), Permit.. = c("06-SE-1812147", 
    "06-SS-1813516", "06-SS-1813699", "06-SE-1814032", "06-SE-1814924", 
    "06-SS-1820333"), Owner.Name.Agent = c("Tiny Tots Academy, Inc Mike Davis", 
    "Ernesto & Elizabeth Diaz Ensign Pools", "DSL Contruction & Investments LLC", 
    "BSD North Federal LLC EPOCA Plumbing Corp", "Maria Silva Parkwood Pools And Pavers LLC", 
    "HPA Borrower Westland Plumbing"), X = c("NA NA", "NA NA", 
    "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA", "NA NA"), Project.Address.City = c("61111 Washington Street Hollywood, 33024", 
    "1224 SW 170 Avenue SW Ranches, 33331", "1233 NW 6 Place Plantation, 33325", 
    "1231 N Federal Hwy Hollywood, 33020", "3223 Dawson Street", 
    "3691 SW 31 Avenue Fort Lauderdale")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Code:

library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df = df %>% grepl("Abandonement", df$Date_Received) %>% str_replace(df$AP) #.... stuck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(AP = ifelse(grepl("Abandonment", Date_Received, fixed = TRUE), gsub("AP", "AB", AP), AP))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 8
     id Date_Received           Date_Approved AP        Permit..      Owner.Name.Agent                          X     Project.Address.City          
  <int> <chr>                   <chr>         <chr>     <chr>         <chr>                                     <chr> <chr>                         
1     1 Addition 1/2/2018       1/2/2018      AP-18-001 06-SE-1812147 Tiny Tots Academy, Inc Mike Davis         NA NA 61111 Washington Street Holly…
2     2 Swimming Pool 1/8/2018  1/8/2018      AP-18-002 06-SS-1813516 Ernesto & Elizabeth Diaz Ensign Pools     NA NA 1224 SW 170 Avenue SW Ranches…
3     3 Swimming Pool 1/8/2018  1/8/2018      AP-18-003 06-SS-1813699 DSL Contruction & Investments LLC         NA NA 1233 NW 6 Place Plantation, 3…
4     4 Abandonment 1/9/2018    1/9/2018      AB-18-004 06-SE-1814032 BSD North Federal LLC EPOCA Plumbing Corp NA NA 1231 N Federal Hwy Hollywood,…
5     5 Swimming Pool 1/12/2017 1/12/2017     AP-18-005 06-SE-1814924 Maria Silva Parkwood Pools And Pavers LLC NA NA 3223 Dawson Street            
6     6 Abandonment 2/5/2018    2/5/2018      AB-18-006 06-SS-1820333 HPA Borrower Westland Plumbing            NA NA 3691 SW 31 Avenue Fort Lauder…
```